# Wait/notify for shared object causes main thread to hang

Tags: java, multithreading, quartz-scheduler

At the outset let me confess that I am quite an experienced Java developer to be aware of wait/notify problems, but have not been getting clues and that's why felt that more inputs from people can help when we are stuck in something and missing the obvious. I am writing a test to verify a Quartz job class and I do it as follows (Sample):

```
   public class SchedulerTest {
       private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
       @Test
       public void shouldValidateSomethingInJob() {
           Object[] paramsForTesting = ...
           SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
           Scheduler scheduler = sf.getScheduler();
           ...
           CustomJobListenerSupport jobListener =
                new CustomJobListenerSupport(LOCK, paramsForTesting);
           scheduler.getListenerManager().addJobListener(jobListener,
                KeyMatcher.keyEquals(jobKey));
           scheduler.start();
           //        synchronized (LOCK) {
           //            // Wait for scheduler to end to avoid DB rollback before that
           //            LOCK.wait();
           //        }
        }

    private static class CustomJobListenerSupport extends JobListenerSupport        
    {
        private final Object lock;

        public CustomJobListenerSupport(Object lock, Object ... paramsForTesting) {
            ...;
            this.lock = lock;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "TestJobListener";
        }

        @Override
        public void jobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context,
                                   JobExecutionException jobException) {
            if (isNotBlank(jobException.getMessage())) {
                try {
                    cleanup(context.getScheduler());
                } catch (SchedulerException e) {
                    logger.error(e);
                }
                throw new RuntimeException(jobException);
            }

            performAssertions();
            try {
                cleanup(context.getScheduler());
            } catch (SchedulerException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        private void performAssertions() {
            // Some assertions
        }

        @SneakyThrows
        private void cleanup(Scheduler scheduler) throws SchedulerException {
            scheduler.clear();
            scheduler.shutdown();
            System.out.println("\nLock in cleanup: "+lock);
            synchronized (lock) {
                lock.notify();
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Now with the wait code commented out, the test completes but fails because DB changes are rolled back before the scheduler can complete, while if I put the wait the main thread seems to hang (atleast it took very long and did not seem to end) and I am not able to figure out if the job is still running because Junit is not writing the HTML report which contains the log statements. The debug statements indicate that both the classes are using the same LOCK object. Agreed that there are better options than using plain object to lock, but want to try them later as I am not familiar with classes like `ReentrantLock`

Any pointers will be of much help.

Thanks,
Paddy

Comment: Use your debugger, and check if the cleanup method is called, and if the lock.notify() is executed. It should probably be in a finally block somewhere to make sure it's always executed, no matter what.

Comment: Maybe notify is called before wait.
Add flag that checks if notify was already called.

Comment: Hi all, I debugged it and find it strange that when I comment the wait portion, the program reaches the service class called by the job or in other words the job runs but when I wait it is never triggered. The scheduler is supposed to be a separate thread, how come it is never called if main thread enters wait queue? It is puzzling